# Need help with a file path validation regular expression

Tags: regex

I am using a RegularExpressionValidator in visual studio and I am struggling to create the correct regular expression for my needs. Here is what I want:

The input can contain any character except `<>:"/|?*`
Also, the input can not contain two backslashes in a row

So, `your\mom` would be ok but `your\\mom` would fail as would `your*mom`

The closest I have come at this point is something like

```
^(?=.*[^<>:"/|?*])(?:[^\\]+|\\(?:$|[^\\])).{0,100}$
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? What about using the substring function to check that 1. none of <>:"/|?* is a substring of the input and 2. \\ is not a substring of the input?

Comment: Well, I suppose I could have used a custom validator and coded it to do that but the solution below works great so I'm gonna call it good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*\\\\)[^<>:"/|?*]*$
```

should do it.

`(?!.*\\\\)` asserts that there are no two backslashes in a row in the string.

`[^<>:"/|?*]*` matches any number of characters except the ones inside the character class.

That is, unless you're talking about the regex features of Visual Studio (the IDE environment itself) which has a wildly nonstandard regex flavor.