# Regular Expression for validating Windows-based file paths including UNC paths

Tags: regex, path

I wanted to validate a file name along with its full path. I tried certain Regular Expressions as below but none of them worked correctly.

```
^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$
and
^(([a-zA-Z]\:)|(\\))(\\{1}|((\\{1})[^\\]([^/:*?<>""|]*))+)$
etc...
```

My requirement is as mentioned below:
Lets say if the file name is "c:\Demo.txt" then it should check every possibilites like no double slash should be included(`c:\\Demo\\demo.text`) no extra colon like(`c::\Demo\demo.text`). Should accept UNC files like(`\\staging\servers`) and others validation as well. Please help. I am really stuck here.

Comment: not homework actually. Some important work has been stuck bcoz of this.

Comment: If your file is uploaded then are you really concerned by the path name or only on the filename part?

Comment: File is getting uploaded, as their are no validation applied to it. I just want to provide validation to the file name. Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C# check that filename is *possibly* valid (not that it exists)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/in-c-sharp-check-that-filename-is-possibly-valid-not-that-it-exists)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063418/need-help-with-a-file-path-validation-regular-expression) contains a partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not using the File class ?
Always use it !

```
File f = null;
string sPathToTest = "C:\Test.txt";
try{
f = new File(sPathToTest );
}catch(Exception e){
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The file \"{0}\" is not a valid path, Error : {1}.", sPathToTest , e.Message);
}
```

MSDN :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Maybe you're just looking for File.Exists ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.80%29.aspx )

Also take a look to the Path class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx )

The GetAbsolutePath could be one way to get what you want! ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx )

```
string sPathToTest = "C:\Test.txt";
string sAbsolutePath = "";
try{
   sAbsolutePath = Path.GetAbsolutePath(sPathToTest);
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sAbsolutePath)){
     Console.WriteLine("Path valid");
   }else{
     Console.WriteLine("Bad path");
   }
}catch(Exception e){
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The file \"{0}\" is not a valid path, Error : {1}.", sPathToTest , e.Message);

}
```

Comment: I have tried this also. but it was not good in helping. So I thought of going for Regular Expression..

Comment: The file will be uploaded. the name of the file is coming in request

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to use exception-handling for validating inputs as it incurs significant computational overhead.

Comment: I agree, but I don't see any other way in this case. Maybe doing a File.Exist if it's a local path (not unc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in the filename part (and not the whole path because you get the file via upload) then you could try something like this:

```
string uploadedName =  @"XX:\dem<<-***\demo.txt";

int pos = uploadedName.LastIndexOf("\\");
if(pos > -1)
    uploadedName = uploadedName.Substring(pos+1);

var c = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
if(uploadedName.IndexOfAny(c) != -1)
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid name");
else
     Console.WriteLine("Acceptable name");
```

This will avoid the use of Exceptions as method to drive the logic of your code.